# Can ASP.NET performance be improved with modules/static classes?

Tags: asp.net, performance, module, shared

Can using Modules or Shared/Static references to the BLL/DAL improve the performance of an ASP.NET website?

I am working of a site that consists of two projects, one the website, the other a VB.NET class library which acts as a combination of DAL and BLL.

The library is used to communicate with  databases and sometimes transform/validate the data going into/coming from the DBs. 
Currently each page on the site that needs db access (vast majority) will create an instance of the relevant class in the library to access specific tables.

As I understand it this leads to a class from the library being instantiated and garbage collected for each request, with the possibility of multiple concurrent instances if multiple users view the same page.

If I converted the classes to modules (shared/static class) would performance increase and memory be saved as only one instance of each module exists at a time and a new instance is not having to be created for each request?

(if so, does anyone know if having TableAdapters as global variables in the modules would cause problems due to threading?)

Alternatively would making the references to the Library class it the ASP.NET page have the same effect? (except I would have to re-write a lot less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but think that the absence of examples of this static class / session object model in books and online is indicative of it being *a bad idea*.

I  inherited a Linq-To-Sql application where the db contexts were static, and after *n* requests the whole thing just fell apart. The standard model for L2Sql is the Unit-of-Work pattern (define a task or set of tasks - do them and close). Let the framework worry about connection pooling and efficient GC.

Are you just trying to be efficient or do you have performance issues? If the latter it's usually more effective to look at caching or improving query efficiency (use stored procedures, root out queries in loops) than looking at object instantiation.

Statics don't play well with unit tests either (another reason why they have dropped out of fashion).

Comment: I was looking at improving the sites efficiency, i will look for a different way to do so now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

instances are only a problem if they are not collected by the CG (a memory leak). Instances are more flexible than static as well because you can configure the instance to the specific context you are using.

When an application has poor performance or memory problems its usually a sign that

1. instances are not properly released (IDisposable)
2. the amount of data retrieved is too big (not paging large sets of data)
3. a large number of queries are executed (select n+1, or just a lot of queries)
4. poorly constructed sql statements (missing indexes, FK, too many joins, etc)
5. too many remote calls (either to other servers, or disk)

These are first things I would check. then start looking at the number of instantiated objects. Chances are that correcting the above mentioned list will solve most performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can using Modules or Shared/Static references to the BLL/DAL improve
>   the performance of an ASP.NET website?

It's possible, but it depends heavily on how you use your data. One tradeoff in using a single shared instance of an object instead of one per request is that you will need to apply locking unless the objects are strictly read-only, and locking can both slow things down and complicate your code (not to mention being a common source of bugs).

However, if each object is going to contain the exact same data, then the tradeoff may be worth it -- even more so if it can save a DB round-trip.

You might consider using either a Singleton or a small number of parameterized objects rather than a static, though -- and use caching to manage them. That would give you the flexibility to let go of objects that you no longer need, which is harder to do when you're dealing with statics.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I suppose even if i had got it to work it would be the same number of DB trips, that are called from fewer objects, and its the Db trips that would be the most time/resource consuming